# codeigniter fetching weird symbols from points

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to return json  back to the users from mysql data using codeigniter. In mysql I have one of the columns as points and when I am calling mysql to get the data it looks like this when I `var_dump` the information.

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (10) { 
 ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["contact_email"]=> string(25) "awesome@awsm.com" 
 ["owner_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["point"]=> string(25) "}�#�N@���ޯ�8@" 
}
```

Because of the points, when I try to json encode and decode and send it back to the user I get `NULL` value.
I am not sure how to fix this, is it a codeigniter issue or how I set my the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `contact_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `point` Point NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  SPATIAL INDEX point_sx (`point`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

This is how the insert statement looks like

```
INSERT INTO foo (contact_email,owner_id, point) VALUES ('awesome@awsm.com', 1, POINT('60.168607847624095','24.932371066131623'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you insertion process, try to insert it like below, hopefully you will get it right

```
$this->db->set("contact_email",'awesome@awsm.com');
$this->db->set("owner_id",1);
$this->db->set("point",'geomfromtext("POINT(60.168607847624095,24.932371066131623)")',false);
$this->db->insert("foo");
```